# How to create this Linq function?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, linq-to-objects

I've got an object like this:

```
Tuple<Question, Levels[]>

// question, { easy, medium, hard }
```

`Levels` is an enum with four options: Easy, Medium, Hard and Expert.

And I want that for each enum which contains the tuple, LINQ function deliver a `Dictionary<Question, Levels>`. For example

If my tuple has three levels, the dictionary should have three values,

```
// question, Easy
// question, Medium
// question, Hard
```

Comment: So the question is the same for every level and it's the key in the dictionary? That would fail on runtime.

Comment: Best you can do: `Dictionary<Question, Levels[]>`

Comment: well that's right, a dictionary should be the best way, maybe a Tuple instead of Dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have noted the question isn't very clear. I've made an attempt to show you various things that you might be wanting to do:

```
var stuff = new Tuple<Question, Levels[]>[] {
      // .... 
    };

var flattened = stuff.SelectMany(tup => 
     tup.Item2.Select(Level => new { tup.Question, Level }));

var grouped = flattened.GroupBy(flat => flat.Level);

// now you can do
var easyOnes = grouped[Levels.Easy];
var mediumOnes = grouped[Levels.Medium];
```

Answer (score 0):

I question whether a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is actually what you are after, as this requires unique keys.

The closest you could get is by perhaps using the [`ToLookup<TKey, TElement>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549073.aspx) extension method:

```
var tuple = new Tuple<Question, Levels[]>(question, 
    new [] { Levels.Easy, Levels.Medium, Levels.Hard});

var questionLevels = tuple.Item2.ToLookup(level => tuple.Item1);

// questionLevels contains:
// question, Levels.Easy
// question, Levels.Medium
// question, Levels.Hard
```

This can then be used to get all of the levels for a question:

```
var levels = questionLevels[question];
// levels contains:
// Levels.Easy
// Levels.Medium
// Levels.Hard
```